# Why were the XML import of an article in ShopWare 5.4.6 Data only partially taken into account?

Tags: xml, import, shopware

I have imported an article using XML file via Shopware backend.

There was a positive message [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRih5.jpg) and even implicitly a suplier was created in database [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ArNc.jpg) (but no matching article in Item overview [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK3f2.jpg) ).

Unfortunately the article is not in the frontend, not in the backend [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK3f2.jpg) and is not included in the database table [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybR1m.jpg).

1. Why was data only partially taken into account when importing articles?
2. Why was suplier crated in mysql [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ArNc.jpg) but not visible in 'Item overview' [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK3f2.jpg).
3. Why was there no error message?
4. Maybe it's still an error in the XML file. Which one could that be?

Thats the source of this XML ( import 1articel with space bordered string supplier.xml ):

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
<articles>
<article>
    <prices><price>
            <group>EK</group>
            <price>2.99</price>
            <pseudoprice></pseudoprice>
            <baseprice></baseprice>
        </price></prices>
    <tax>19.00</tax>
    <category><categories>101</categories></category>
    <active>1</active>
    <ordernumber>ordernumber: space bordered string supplier</ordernumber>
    <name>name: space bordered string supplier</name>
    <mainnumber>9</mainnumber>
    <supplier>   space bordered string supplier   </supplier>
</article>
</articles>
</Root>`
```

[image: Importing finished successfully. 1 of 1]

[image: yes new timed row in database phpmyadmin]

[image: Manufacturer administration. See line 4]

[image: no matching article in Item overview (backend)]

[image: no matching article in phpmyadmin]

Comment: Is there an XSD or other XML schema you could use to validate your message?  I don't work with ShopWare but `<category><categories>101</categories></category>` looks inside out.  I'd think `<categories><category>101</category></categories>` would make more sense.

Comment: @kjhughes There is a example XML:  https://community.shopware.com/files/DataImportExport/ArticleMinimal.xml
I use this (last days) preconfigured Virtualbox: https://github.com/sl5net/lubuntu-shopware-stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating products without variants, the ordernumber has to be the same as the mainnumber. Those will only differ, when this is a variant product (and even in this case one of the variants will have ordernumber = mainnumber). Because of this, your example won't work (it is a valid import, because if there would be an article with this mainnumber, the product might be assigned to it as variant).